# Color a word from imported text file, and save as formatted word document

Tags: r, officer

I'm trying to color a set of words, for example word1 and word2 from an imported word document using the officer package in R. I am now stuck after setting the text properties for the word.

I've read the data file using `read_docx(filename)`, where filename is a txt file. I've also set the text properties using `fp_text()` and `ftext()`.

```
my_doc <- read_docx(file.path(filepath,myfile)) 

color1 <- fp_text(color = "blue", font.size = 10, bold = FALSE,
        italic = FALSE, underlined = FALSE, font.family = "Arial",
        vertical.align = "baseline", shading.color = "transparent")
ftext("word1", color1)
color2 <- fp_text(color = "red", font.size = 10, bold = FALSE,
        italic = FALSE, underlined = FALSE, font.family = "Arial",
        vertical.align = "baseline", shading.color = "transparent")
ftext("word2", color1)
```

However, if my text is something like `This is my text. word1 should be colored blue, and word2 should be colored red`, how do I set the word in the text to the color, and how do I save it into a formatted word document with the color applied?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```r
color1 <- fp_text(color = "blue", font.size = 10, bold = FALSE,
        italic = FALSE, underlined = FALSE, font.family = "Arial",
        vertical.align = "baseline", shading.color = "transparent")
ftext("word1", color1)
color2 <- fp_text(color = "red", font.size = 10, bold = FALSE,
        italic = FALSE, underlined = FALSE, font.family = "Arial",
        vertical.align = "baseline", shading.color = "transparent")
ftext("word2", color2)


fpar_1 <- fpar(ftext("word1", color1), "?")
fpar_2 <- fpar(ftext("word2", color2), "?")

my_doc <- read_docx() %>%
body_add_fpar(fpar_1) %>%
body_add_fpar(fpar_2)
```